# A better way to count multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql

My schema for the worship songs module of a church management website looks like:

**songs** - id, name

**song_books** - id, name, available

**books_songs** - many to many relationships between songs and song books, every song can have a number in multiple books, and really any number will do if a church uses multiple books.

**song_tracks** - id, date, leader, service - unique constraint on date and service.

**songs_led** - id, track_id, song_id - list of songs led for a particular tracked day.

The query below gets a list of songs led over a time range, a book name and number, as well as the number of times it was led.

The `...as "count"` statement was

```
COUNT(`l`.`song_id`)
```

before, but it doubled the count when a song appeared in multiple books, so I divided by the number of available books a song appeared in.

```
SELECT `s`.`name`,
       `s`.`id`,
       `bs`.`number`,
       `b`.`name` AS `bname`,
       CEIL(COUNT(`l`.`song_id`)/
              (SELECT COUNT(songs.id)
               FROM songs
               LEFT JOIN books_songs ON books_songs.song_id = songs.id
               AND books_songs.book_id IN
                 (SELECT id
                  FROM song_books
                  WHERE available <> 0)
               WHERE songs.id = s.id)) AS `count`
FROM `songs` AS `s`
JOIN `songs_led` AS `l` ON (`l`.`song_id` = `s`.`id`)
JOIN `books_songs` AS `bs` ON (`bs`.`song_id` = `s`.`id`)
JOIN
  (SELECT *
   FROM song_books
   WHERE available <> 0
   ORDER BY name ASC) AS `b` ON (`bs`.`book_id` = `b`.`id`)
JOIN `song_tracks` AS `t` ON (`l`.`track_id` = `t`.`id`)
WHERE `t`.`date` >= '2013-10-29'
  AND `t`.`date` <= '2013-12-28'
GROUP BY `s`.`id`
ORDER BY `count` DESC,
         `s`.`name`,
         `b`.`name`
```

Is there a better way to do this? I hope not to get into this kind of join hell in future.

Comment: Does this query give you the right count? `select count(*) from song_tracks where date between ? and ?;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each song has its own ID even if it appears in multiple books, then you may be able to use

```
   COUNT(DISTINCT song_id)
```

to avoid double-counting the ones that appear in multiple books.

Comment: Thank you! I'm an idiot -- I wonder why this completely escaped me? In this case I used `DISTINCT l.id` as what I'm counting is the number of times led per song.

Comment: There's a lot of sophistication behind most of the aggregate (GROUP BY) functions; and it's sometimes hard to know what it all is.